# Jquery delegate() deprecated , then how to listen dynamic create object event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery delegate() deprecated , then how to listen dynamic create object event

FOR Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).find("p").on("click", function(event) {
    $("#contain").append("<p>Click this paragraph </p>" + event.timeStamp);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click this paragraph.</p>
<div id="contain"></div>
```

Here contain>p click event not happened with `on` event delegate is working is there any idea for this instead of delegate() or live() ?

Comment: Here you go with the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used wrong syntax, Correct syntax is:

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

Which makes your code:

```
$(document).on("click","p", function(event) {
  $("#contain").append("<p>Click this paragraph </p>" + event.timeStamp);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Delegate like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click","p", function(event) {
    $("#contain").append("<p>Click this paragraph </p>" + event.timeStamp);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click this paragraph.</p>
<div id="contain"></div>
```